# Install fb-python on Linux machine

Tags: python, lua, torch, glog

I am trying to install fb-python library -a bridge between Lua and Python:
https://github.com/facebookarchive/fblualib/tree/master/fblualib/python

on my Linux machine using the command

```
cd fblualib/fblualib/python
luarocks make rockspec/fbpython-0.1-1.rockspec
```

however all my attempts are encountering the error below:

```
    cmake -E make_directory build &&
    cd build &&
    cmake -DROCKS_PREFIX=/home/current_user/torch/install/lib/luarocks/rocks/fbpython/0.1-1 \
          -DROCKS_LUADIR=/home/current_user/torch/install/lib/luarocks/rocks/fbpython/0.1-1/lua \
          -DROCKS_LIBDIR=/home/current_user/torch/install/lib/luarocks/rocks/fbpython/0.1-1/lib \
          .. &&
    make

CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:108 (message):
  REQUIRED_ARGS (missing: GLOG_INCLUDE_DIR GLOG_LIBRARY)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:315 
(_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  cmake/FindGlog.cmake:21 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
  CMakeLists.txt:27 (FIND_PACKAGE)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

The file throwing the error is this: https://github.com/facebookarchive/fblualib/blob/master/fblualib/cmake/FindGlog.cmake

However, I have installed the Glog library https://github.com/google/glog/releases: given that I don't have sudo access to the machine, I set ./configure to a custom location that I probably need to specify now for the GLOG_INCLUDE_DIR and GLOG_LIBRARY flags. How to do this? Any suggestion is appreciated. Thank you!